# Java applications do not work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, oracle, cache

I have had working Java environment til Yesterday, I cleared my all files and folders in /tmp/ then restarted my computer after that I **can not get any Java applications (Chrome, Firefox, Thunderbird, and etc) to work** on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer.

I started Google Chrome and checked the System Monitor processes, process chrome status changed from uninterrupted to running and suddenly it gone away from the process list.

If anyone can suggest how debug this issue I would be grateful.

NOTE: I work on Oracle Java 1.8.0.25

Comment: Rebooting your computer cleans out all files in `/tmp` automatically, so next time, just reboot.  In this case, if you would have a system backup, just restoring your system backup  would take you 5 minutes to be back where you were  before this heppened. Look at [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) how to perform one in the future.

Comment: That being said, does this also happen in the guest session?

Comment: @Fabby no, I don't have a system backup set up, but I will in future

Comment: @Fabby yes, this happens also in the guest session

Comment: I'm sorry to not have been much help for now, but hopefully I'll have helped you for the future...  (and you haven't read the article: You're user type 4)

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Thunderbird are no Java applications. Is the problem still present?